# Display text in website using WebSocketServer & Arduino

Tags: websocket, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm looking to do the following: 
I have a device that receives data from a website, in this case to light up an LED. However, I would like to do the reverse now, where I can click a physical button on the device (to trigger code) and send a message to display on the website. The website itself is just simple HTML, and I'm using the ESP8266 to send the data over wifi, programmed using arduino code and the WebSocketServer library. I'm not quite sure how to get a message across, nor how to actually display it within the website. I apologize if this is quite easy, but I'be been wracking my head for two hours trying to find it online, and have had no luck. Cheers!

Comment: I think you just want to send data over wifi to website

Answer (score 0):

In reference to http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Esp8266-Post-Data-to-Website/ blog by [Khalilm](http://www.instructables.com/member/Khalilm/) , It seems to be much easy for accomplishing your aim.He explains it in six steps.

HTTP works as a request-response protocol between a client and server. A web browser may be the client, and an application on a computer that hosts a web site may be the server. Example: A client (browser) submits an HTTP request to the server; then the server returns a response to the client. The response contains status information about the request and may also contain the requested content. On our example the esp8266 is the client and the server that is hosting our website is the server.

Comment: I wish this would help you

Answer (score 0):

Because HTTP is a request-response protocol, as mentioned above, it's not really about "sending" anything to a browser, but rather of making it available to the browser when someone visits the page, the page is reloaded, or the page "reaches out" to the server with a webservice call, for example, to update part of the page.

However, one twist you could do on your project is:
1. Press the button
2. Record the time in millis() for example.
3. Create a small webpage to show "Button was last pressed at ___ millis()"
4. Then press button whenever you like and refresh the page to see updated time.

Beyond that, you'll need scripting on the browser side to poll the webserver.  Given that you don't really ever "send" to a website, does this idea make sense, a reasonable derivative of what you were attempting?  If so, give it a try and we'll help if you run into problems.